# OSX High Sierra stop applications from auto launching

Tags: high-sierra

This is driving me crazy!
Whenever I reboot in OSX High Sierra all the applications I had open automatically reboot.
In Login Items NONE of these applications are there!

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a standard feature & has been there for years.

It asks you as you shut down or reboot - just uncheck the box, it should remember.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the checkbox mentioned in [Tetsujin's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/305135/66812) answer make sure you don't have any unwanted startup items under

**Apple menu** > **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > **Login Items**.

Make sure you select the unwanted auto-start item and click the <kbd>-</kbd> button since **Hide** will only hide the app from the Dock.

Also, if you reboot by typing `sudo reboot` from terminal, then apparently the setting for `reopen windows` is assumed to be true. In such cases, to avoid auto-starting the apps, after you have entered your password on the login screen, press the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, and then keep holding the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key until the Dock is shown.